# Is this a grammatical error?

Tags: grammar

> Professional interests **continue** to expand, Virgo, and you're managing to keep very busy. Your income is rising, and you could be achieving a certain prominence in your field. Nonetheless, you could be looking for new opportunities. The field you're in now may not be one that you want to continue for the next 20 years. This is therefore a good day to put out a few feelers and test the waters. You might be surprised at the opportunities out there. [*Source*](http://my.horoscope.com/astrology/free-daily-horoscope-virgo.html)

I think it should be "are continuing to expand."

Comment: Could you explain why you think it's mistaken?

Comment: Whether in the present continuous or in the present tense, it means the same thing here?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10332/difference-between-continue-to-and-are-continuing-to

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem unusual or erroneous to me, but I'm a Minnesotan, not an English major. I think I see what you're concerned about, but I don't think inconsistency in the verb tense between the two parts of the sentence, at least comparing "are `x`ing" vs. "`x`", would constitute an error for most ordinary purposes. Also, as @J.R.'s comment points out, it doesn't matter which tense you use first.

There may be some difference of meaning though: see [the related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/10332/3823) mentioned in @snailplane's comment on the OP.

Comment: Not only that, it can go the other way around, too. _The world is passing you by, Virgil, and you just sit on your ass all day with your video games._ The tenses need not match just because they are in the same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Either present simple or present continuous is fine in the context. But remember that present continuous has more immediacy: I am walking to school (right now) (but you might stop walking at any moment). "x is continuing" suggests that, right now, it is continuing, whereas "x continues" connotes a habitual way of behaving, and carries more expectation of the behaviour being continued into the future: I walk to school (usually) and shall likely continue to do so. And, of course, the use of present simple tense complements the meaning of the verb "continue", which makes present simple sound more natural

Consider students sitting an exam, and the teacher says "pens down". "You are continuing to write" means you are still writing, right now, when you shouldn't be, whereas "You continue to write...." would be the form used outside of the immediate situation, for a student who continually, or often, continues to write when they shouldn't during exams.

But this is almost an overanalysis, as, in many contexts, the choice between these tenses is a free one. In such cases, fluent speakers go "by ear", with what sounds more natural.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a conflict of tenses. *Interests continue to expand... you're managing... is rising...* (then some conditionals) then *put out feelers... test the waters.*

It is like saying, *There is an ongoing expansion...*

*I think that to live for today is a good philosophy, but that planning for the future is also good.* These, too, are all occurring now.